# In Python: print a list indice with a str var

Tags: python, list

It says:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This is why this code doesn't work for me:

```py
list1 = ["unity1", "unity2", "unity3"]
choice1 = str(input("Write your option:")) #user types 1
print("Your choice is ", list1[choice1])
```

If `list1[1]` would print "unity2", why doesn't `list1[choice1]` make the same result because choice1 == 1 ?

I would like it to print "unity2". Do you know any alternative to print one element of a list based on a user choice ? Thank you

Comment: You want `choice1 = int(input("Write your option:"))`

Comment: *"why doesn't 'list1[choice1]' make the same result"* — Because you're actually doing `list1["1"]`!

Comment: Think of `indicies` here as numerical ordering of elements in a list, you can't check the numerical ordering with a string, which you define by your `str(input())`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a string as an input index. Be aware you need to change the type to Integer using

```
choice1 = int(choice1)
```

before doing

```
print("Your choice is ", list1[choice1])
```